# Has a quintesson judge ever found someone guilty?

Tags: transformers

We see the "mockery of justice" on Quintesson in Transformers: The Movie, in which parties found innocent are executed by the Sharkticons.

In Transformers canon has a Quintesson judge ever found someone guilty? If so, what has happened to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, and the punishment was death.

The Quintessons found Wreck-Gar's torturer, [Mister Regan](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Mister_Regan), guilty in the UK version of [The Big Broadcast of 2006](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Big_Broadcast_of_2006_%28issue%29), a 1988 comic. The torturer was to extract information from Wreck-Gar, to further the Quintesson war agenda.  When Wreck-Gar recounted his story -- the American version of The Big Broadcast, which has continuity issues with the UK's comic line. Knowing that Wreck-Gar was full of slag, the Quintessons judged his torturer as incompetent and sentenced him to death.

[image: Regan]

As for whether or not you consider the UK comics canon is an entirely different matter.

Comment: This story sounds amazing. The UK comics did such clever things to play around with their difficult relationship to the American books.

Comment: Wow. That's a really smart way to play with the fourth wall and canon. Is the execution portrayed too? Would it be a similar drop into a pit of sharkticons?

Comment: @StuperUser It isn't shown. Wreck-Gar says good night to the audience and that's the end of the issue. That said, Quintesson ships appear to be almost entirely standing areas and Sharkticon tanks. When all you have is a hammer...